# C++ Using operator overloading to add two time values

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

As the title said, I'm trying to addition two different time values using operator overloading. For example:

```
r1=10:00     
r2=15:50          
r3=18:20

r4=r1+r2=25:50   
r5=r1+r3=28:20           
r6=r2+r3=34:10
```

I've managed to do that with this part of a class named 'Clock':

```
Clock Clock::operator+(int m){
int sum;
sum=hour+m+(minu+m)/60;
sum=(minu+m)%60;
return sum;
}
```

But, what I want is to make the time a 24 hour format. 
So instead of:

```
r4=r1+r2= 25:50    
r5=r1+r3= 28:20    
r6=r2+r3= 34:10
```

It would be:

```
r4=r1+r2= 01:50    
r5=r1+r3= 04:20    
r6=r2+r3= 10:10
```

Can anybody show me a suggestion to solve this?

Comment: If your time is `24:00` or bigger then subtract 24 hours

Answer (score 1):

You're aware of `std::chrono` ? Because you might be reinventing the wheel.

Anyway, what you add to a time is a time difference. And if you subtract two times, you get a time difference. You can't add 5 to a time, but you can add 5 minutes or 5 seconds.

That said, if you just have the non-date part of a time, you can indeed wrap around every 24 hours. You already know how to wrap around every 60 minutes; hours work the same. (And if you did have a day counter, you'd have to increment that by one whenever the hours wrapped around - again just like minutes overflow into hours).